# Explain a SELECT statement for MySQL

Tags: mysql, database

someone can explain me what this query does?

```
$sql=mysql_query("SELECT b.id, b.data FROM data_parent a, data b WHERE b.id=a.did and parent='$id'");
```

it works but honestly i didn't understand.

Thanks

Comment: Does this make any more sense to you? `SELECT b.id, b.data FROM data_parent a JOIN data b ON b.id=a.did WHERE parent='$id'`. Would help if you told us which table `parent` is in as well.

Comment: your code also works well. i must study the foreign key relation. i have really problems with this type of syntax

Comment: "someone can explain me what this query does?" - yes, the query is used to expose you to SQL injection :)

Comment: @taspeotis you can also provide an answer that solve the situation. thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. Take the table `data_parent` and alias it as `a`.
2. Take the table `data` and alias it as `b`.
3. Match values in `a` with those in `b` on the `id` column in `b` and the `did` column in `a`.
4. Filter for rows in [some table since it isn't specified] such that the column `parent` is equal to some passed in value.
5. From those results, display the `id` and `data` columns from `b`

Answer (score 0):

The query grabs the COlumns ID & Data from the Data table where the data_parentID is the same as the data table id. And it is based on for 1 parent ID